# how to hide a div if a Listview is empty in asp .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How should I hide the Attach div if the ListView2 is Empty.

```
<div id="Attach" class="AttachHead col-lg-12">
                    <h2>
                        Attachments</h2>
                </div>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href='<%# String.Format("Download.aspx?Title={0}",Container.DataItem) %>' target="_blank">
                            <asp:Label ID="attach" runat="Server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>' CssClass="col-lg-4" />
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I am assuming this is in a repeater correct ?

Comment: listview contains a list of items. If its empty i want to hide the div

Comment: Can't you check in the code behind if list is empty, `visible=false`. Or are you asking just particular index of a list ?

Comment: yes i can.. but i only want not to display the Attach div if the listview is emty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add runat="server" attribute to the div first.

```
<div runat="server" id="Attach" class="AttachHead col-lg-12"> <h2> Attachments</h2></div>
```

Then register the databound event of listview.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server" ondatabound="ListView2_DataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href='<%# String.Format("Download.aspx?Title=    {0}",Container.DataItem) %>' target="_blank">
                        <asp:Label ID="attach" runat="Server" Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>' CssClass="col-lg-4" />
                    </a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

and check with `ListView2.items.count` inside the databound method in codebehind like:

```
protected void ListView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ListView2.Items.Count > 0)
        Attach.Visible = true;
    else
        Attach.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to alter your markup and do it in client-side, try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Attach").css("display", $(".col-lg-4").length ? "block" : "none");
});
```

The above code assumes that there is a `PostBack` on `DataBind` of the `ListView`. If you are using the *unholy* `UpdatePanel` change the `DOM Ready` event to `pageLoad` function like this

```
function pageLoad() {
    $("#Attach").css("display", $(".col-lg-4").length ? "block" : "none");
}
```